# C# SourceCodeGenerator Net5 does not work

Tags: c#

I'm testing an example of the source code generator that just doesn't want to run.

An error comes back. If there is a hook on the linet: context.AddSource( ... at a breakpoint it says:
SourceText error CS0119: 'SourceText' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Google couldn't find anything specific about it either.

Here is the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

namespace CodeGeneratorLibrary
{
    [Generator]
    public class CodeGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        GeneratorInitializationContext _InitializationContext;
        GeneratorExecutionContext _ExecutionContext;

        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            _InitializationContext = context;
        }

        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            _ExecutionContext = context;

            // Start building C# code
            StringBuilder sourceBuilder = new StringBuilder(@"

            using System;
            namespace Source_Generator_u_COM

            {
                public static class HelloWorld
                {
                    public static void SayHello() 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(""The following syntax trees existed in the compilation that created this program:"");
                        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(""Test HelloWorld"");

                    }
                }
            }");


            //// Get a list of syntax trees (.cs files)
            //var syntaxTrees = context.Compilation.SyntaxTrees;

            //// Add output of each file path for each syntax tree
            //foreach (SyntaxTree tree in syntaxTrees)
            //{
            //    sourceBuilder.AppendLine($@"Console.WriteLine(@"" - {tree.FilePath}"");");
            //}

            //// Close generated code block
            //sourceBuilder.Append(@"
            //        }
            //    }
            //}");


            // Inject the created source
            context.AddSource("HelloWorld.cs", SourceText.From(sourceBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that *should* work fine... comparison: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.BuildTools/Generators/ProtoFileGenerator.cs#L236 - is this failing at build? or at runtime? and do you have any other types called `SourceText` locally?

Comment: Just checked and your code compiles and works perfectly fine calling `Source_Generator_u_COM.HelloWorld.SayHello();`. Source gen. [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/)

Comment: Then I wonder why it doesn't work for me. when I start, I get a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. And I do not know why. If I set a breakpoint at this point, there is an error text above the corresponding object as described above.

SourceText error CS0119: 'SourceText' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: The error occurs after the build at run time